# .htaccess and .htpasswd throwing 500 internal server error

Tags: htaccess

I've created a .htaccess and a .htpasswd file, both using my hosting's tool, uploaded them, and I get an error when I try to view the directory. Why?

*my .htaccess file:*

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/u947248131/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

Comment: What version of Apache are you using, and what is the error in the `error_log`?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the `AuthType` line before `AuthName`